# What are the benefits of reciting Durga Saptashati Devi Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram?

Tags: worship, durga, stotra

Navarathri is a very important festival of the Hindus. This is a festival during  which Devi ie Goddess Durga, is worshipped for nine nights.

Goddess  Durga  is worshipped in various forms on each day, of the Navarathri festival. On day 1 is worshipped  Devi Shailaputri{variously known as Sati Bhavani, Parvati or Hemavati{also spelled as Hymavati- for daughter of Himavan}.

And like that for the next eight days ,Goddess Durga is worshipped in other forms viz Devi Brahmacharini,Chandraghanta,Kushmanda{or Ashtabhuja Devi},Skandamata{also known as Devi Padmasana},Kathyayini,Kaalratri{also called Devi Shubhamkari},Mahagauri and Siddhidhatri.

Durga Saptashati Devi Apradha Kshamapana Strotram,is also recited
 during Navarathri.

What is the significance of Durga Saptashati Devi Apradha Kshamapana Stotram?

What are the benefits of reciting Durga Saptashati Devi Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram?

Comment: Aparadha Kshamapana stotram is usually recited after a recital or after the completion of Puja.Its like asking for forgiveness from Goddess for various mistakes that one mite have done during the recital/puja including (but not limited to) mispronounciations of mantra ,omissions of bindu visargas etc,not showing proper mudras etc.During God's Pujas as well a shorter adapted version of the same stotra is recited.With sureswari/parameswari.devi being replaced by sureswara/parameswara/deva respectively.

Comment: Hymavati i.e. daughter of Himavan. Can you please edit suitably?

Comment: The 9 forms of Devi Durga worshiped during navaratri are collectively called Navadurga :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navadurga

Comment: Wikipedia is not always right. My personal choice would be to side with the correct rather than the popular. Up to you of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Devi Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/devi_durga-devi_aparadha_kshamapana_stotram.php) was composed by **Adi Shankaracharya**.It is usually customary to recite the stotram after the completion of a Chandi Patha recital or after the completion of any Devi Puja.

It is like asking for forgiveness from Mother Goddess for the various offences(like not uttering Mantras correctly,not showing Mudras properly or  even  general offences) one might have committed during the recital/puja(or otherwise).

The theme of this Storam is of total surrender to Mother Goddess and asking Her for forgiveness. Just like a mother never abandons her son ,no matter how many mistakes he might have committed,similarly this stotram asks Goddess to protect & forgive us like Her son.

The benefits of reciting(honestly) the stotram is obviously getting forgiven by Mother Goddess of the offences and sins one has committed.

The Stotram has 12 verses in all ,few are given below(with meaning).

A similar  Aparadha Kshamapana Stotram dedicated to Lord Shiva is [this](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Shivaparadha_kshamapana_stotram)

> न मत्रं नो यन्त्रं तदपि च न जाने स्तुतिमहो न चाह्वानं ध्यानं तदपि च न
>   जाने स्तुतिकथाः । न जाने मुद्रास्ते तदपि च न जाने विलपनं परं जाने
>   मातस्त्वदनुसरणं क्लेशहरणम् ॥१॥
>
> (O mother neither i know your Mantra,our Yantra,your Stuti,your
>   Dhyanam,or even your Mudras.Not even i know how to cry for
>   you.However, one thing I know (for certain); By following You (somehow
>   through rememberance however imperfectly) will take away all my
>   Afflictions (from my Mind),
>
> नाराधितासि विधिना विविधोपचारैः किं रुक्षचिन्तनपरैर्न कृतं वचोभिः ।
>   श्यामे त्वमेव यदि किञ्चन मय्यनाथे धत्से कृपामुचितमम्ब परं तवैव ॥९॥
>
> (O Mother) I have not worshipped You as prescribed by tradition with
>   various rituals, (On the other hand) What rough thoughts did my mind
>   not think and my speech utter?  O Shyama, inspite of this, if You
>   indeed, to a little extent, to this orphan ...  ... have extended Your
>   Grace, O Supreme Mother, It indeed only becomes You (i.e. is possible
>   for You),
>
> आपत्सु मग्नः स्मरणं त्वदीयं करोमि दुर्गे करुणार्णवेशि । नैतच्छठत्वं मम
>   भावयेथाः क्षुधातृषार्ता जननीं स्मरन्ति ॥१०॥
>
> (O Mother) I have sunk in Misfortunes and therefore remembering You
>   now (which I never did before),  O Mother Durga, (You Who are) an
>   Ocean of Compassion, ...  ... (Therefore) do not think of me as false
>   (and my invocation as pretence),  (Because) When children are
>   afflicted with Hunger and Thirst, they naturally remember their Mother
>   (only),
>
> मत्समः पातकी नास्ति पापघ्नी त्वत्समा न हि । एवं ज्ञात्वा महादेवि
>   यथायोग्यं तथा कुरु ॥१२॥
>
> (O Mother) There is no one as Fallen like me, and there is no one as
>   Uplifting ( by removing Sins ) like You,  Considering thus, O
>   Mahadevi, Please do whatever is proper (to save me).