# How to ask God for forgiveness?

Tags: gods, karma

I am a student, and I broke a vow to God. I am sorry for what I did. And now I want to ask God for forgiveness. How can I convince God to forgive me? This may sound like a personal advice, however I strongly feel this is a general question on how to ask forgiveness from God?

Comment: To which god are you praying? Vishnu/Shiva, etc?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38133/prayer-for-requesting-forgiveness-from-god

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prayer for requesting forgiveness from GOD?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38133/prayer-for-requesting-forgiveness-from-god)